# C++, write from file into map

Tags: c++, file, c++17, maps, file-handling

im just new at c++ and I try to read from a file and write the content into a map<string, float>.
But only the first element of my file gets mapped and i cant figuer out why.

The file looks like this:

```
E:16.93
N:10.53
I:8.02
...
```

And the code i got for this part so far:

```
std::map<char, float> frequenciesM;
fstream frequencieFile("frequencies.txt", std::ios::in);

if(!frequencieFile){
        cout << "No such File!";
    }else{
        std::string line;
        char ch;
        std::string sub;
        float fl;
        while (std::getline(frequencieFile, line, '\0')) {
            ch = line[0];
            sub = line.substr(2);
            fl = std::stof(sub);
            frequenciesM[ch] = fl;

        }
    }
```

When i try to print out the size and content of my map, this is what i get:

```
Size: 1
E: 16.93
```

Thx for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Ok, now where in your file does the `\0` character appear? You know, the third parameter to `std::getline` that you're passing, the parameter that tells `std::getline` to keep reading the input until this characer is read, and place everything that gets read, into the 2nd parameter?

Comment: Ahh oke, got it, now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling `getline()` to read until a `'\0'` (nul) character is encountered, but there is no such character in your file, so the entire file gets read into the `string` on the 1st call, and then you extract only the 1st set of values from the `string`, discarding the rest of the data.

To read the file line-by-line, you need to change the 3rd parameter of `getline()` to `'\n'` instead:

```
while (std::getline(frequencieFile, line, '\n'))
```

Or, just drop the 3rd parameter entirely since `'\n'` is the default delimiter:

```
while (std::getline(frequencieFile, line))
```